# Nested promise with Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I've a function to update the DB rows one by one with Parse's promise

```
exports.update = function (items, successHandler, errorHandler) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var Item = Parse.Object.extend("Item");

    Parse.Promise.as().then(function () {
        var promises = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {                
                (function (j) {  //create new closure so i changes with each callback
                    var query = new Parse.Query(Item);
                    query.equalTo("sku", items[j]['sku'];);

                    promises.push(query.find({
                        success: function (results) {
                            if (results.length === 1) {
                                var object = results[0];

                                console.log('Item exists, now updating..');

                                return object.save(items[j]).then(function () {
                                    console.log("Item saved"); // never called, why?

                                }, function (error) {
                                    console.error("Item not saved with error: " + error.message); // never called, why?
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.error("Failure during querying..");
                        }
                    }));
                })(i);
        }

        return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

    }).then(function () {
            return successHandler("Item updated.");
        }, function (error) {
            return errorHandler(error);
        }
    );
};
```

The problem is, the `object.save` is actually called and data is being saved in the DB, however, the following two promises are never called, not matter success or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the following two promises*"?

Comment: If you want to use promises, you probably should not use `success` and `error` callbacks

Comment: Maybe the `(results.length === 1)` condition is never met. Try `(results.length >= 1)`

Comment: And is that a rogue ';' in `query.equalTo("sku", items[j]['sku'];);`?

Answer (score 0):

I think because the Promise you return from your inner success function is not going to be necessarily fulfilled. You better promisify the `query.find()` function with a `.then()` instead

```
promises.push(query.find().then(function(results) {

     if (results.length === 1) {
         var object = results[0];

         console.log('Item exists, now updating..');

         return object.save(items[j]);
    }

    }).then(function() {
         console.log("Item saved"); 

    }, function (error) {
         console.error("Item not saved with error: " + error.message); 
    });

}));
```